# PyQt Tree Drag and Drop Event. Weird action

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, tree, pyqt

I have a Widget window contains two QtTree Widgets. It works fine when I drag and drop items from one tree widget to another tree widget. But If I drag an item and drop it to the same tree widget (which is not a desired behavior, so I disable accept drop in the code), the Tree Widget ignore my next mouse press event.

To reproduce the issue, please run the code and

1.Drag an item from the left tree and drop it the same tree widget.

2.Click any item on the left tree widget, and you will notice nothing change

3.Click same or other item again, and the selection changes.

also, try click the small expend icon after drop an item. No matter how many time you click on the small expend icon, no events.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import cPickle

class MyTreeItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTreeItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)


    def getPath(self):
        """
        Rebuild path from the tree.
        """
        if isinstance(self.parent(), MyTreeItem):
           path = '{0}/{1}'.format(self.parent().getPath() ,str(self.text(0)))
        #The top level item
        else:
           path = '/{0}'.format(str(self.text(0)))

        return path


    def getParents(self):
        """
        Get all the parents to the top level.
        """
        parents = []

        while self:
            self = self.parent()
            if isinstance(self, MyTreeItem):
                parents.append(self)

        return parents


    def getChildren(self):
        """
        Get all the children(flatten).
        """
        children = []
        if not self:
            return children

        childrenCount = self.childCount()

        if childrenCount == 0:
            return children

        for idx in range(childrenCount):
            citem = self.child(idx)
            if citem:
                children.append(citem)
                children.extend(citem.getChildren())

        return children

class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setHeaderLabels(["Select Members"])
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.mousePressPos = QtCore.QPoint(0,0)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(MyTreeWidget, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        #if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        #    self.mousePressPos = event.pos()


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyTreeWidget, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        #length = (event.pos() - self.mousePressPos).manhattanLength()

        #if length < QtGui.QApplication.startDragDistance():
        #    return

        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        mime_data = QtCore.QMimeData()
        passme = []
        for sel in self.selectedItems():
            dnddict = {}
            dnddict['disp'] = sel.getPath()
            dnddict['val'] = sel.getPath()

            passme.append(dnddict)

        bstream = cPickle.dumps(passme)
        mime_data.setData("application/x-ltreedata", bstream)
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        action = drag.exec_()


    def mouseReleaseEven(self, event):
        self.setAcceptDrop(True)
        event.accept()


    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-ltreedata"):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-ltreedata"):
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.source() == self:
            event.ignore()
        else:
            for item in event.source().selectedItems():
                print item.text(0)

    def addItems(self, itemList):
        """
        Take a list of path-like strings
        """
        for item in itemList:
            self.addItem(item)


    def addItem(self, item):
        """
        Convert each item to a tree item
        """
        joints = item.strip('/').split('/')

        joint = None
        while joints:
            joint = self.addTreeJoint(joints.pop(0), joint)


    def addTreeJoint(self, jointName, parent=None):
        """
        Add item to the tree widget
        """
        returnItem = None
        #If it the top of the tree
        if not parent:
            #Find existing item
            for item in self.findItems(QtCore.QString(jointName),QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly):
                if jointName == item.text(0):

                    return item
            #Create new top level item
            returnItem = MyTreeItem(self)
            returnItem.setText(0, jointName)

        #We search all the children of this tree level and figure out if
        #we need to create a new tree item.
        else:
            for idx in range(parent.childCount()):
                if parent.childCount() == 0:
                    break
                if jointName == parent.child(idx).text(0):
                    return parent.child(idx)

            #Create new item
            returnItem = MyTreeItem(parent)
            returnItem.setText(0, jointName)

        return returnItem


class GeometrySelector(QtGui.QWidget):
    accepted = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GeometrySelector, self).__init__(parent)


        self.treeWidget = MyTreeWidget(self)
        self.treeWidget.addItems(get_objs())

        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Add Members', self)
        button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        button.clicked.connect(self.cb_accept)

        filterLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        filterLabel.setText('Filter:')
        filterField = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        filterField.textChanged.connect(self.filterChanged)


        filterBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        filterBox.addWidget(filterLabel)
        filterBox.addWidget(filterField)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget,0,0)
        mainLayout.addLayout(filterBox,1,0)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button,2,0)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QColor(80, 80, 80))
        pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
        self.setPalette(pal)
        button.setPalette(pal)
        self.treeWidget.setPalette(pal)


    def filterChanged(self, filterStr):
        showedItem = []

        matchFlag = QtCore.Qt.MatchFlags(QtCore.Qt.MatchContains | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive | QtCore.Qt.MatchRegExp)
        allItems = self.treeWidget.findItems(QtCore.QString("*"),matchFlag)

        for item in allItems:
            if item in showedItem:
                continue

            if str(filterStr) in str(item.text(0)):
                showedItem.append(item)
                showedItem.extend(item.getParents())
                showedItem.extend(item.getChildren())

        for item in allItems:
            if item in showedItem:
                item.setHidden(False)
            else:
                item.setHidden(True)


    def cb_accept(self):
        selected_things = [str(item.getPath()) for item in self.treeWidget.selectedItems()]
        self.accepted.emit(selected_things)


class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        s1 = GeometrySelector(self)
        s2 = GeometrySelector(self)

        filterBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        filterBox.addWidget(s1)
        filterBox.addWidget(s2)

        self.setLayout(filterBox)


def get_objs():
    obj = ['/home/someone/something/somewhere','/home/someone/something/somewhere1','/home/someone/something/somewhere2',
           '/home/someoneA/something/somewhere','/home/someoneA/somethingA/somewhere','/home/someoneA/somethingA/somewhere',
           '/home/someoneC/something/somewhere','/home/someoneC/something/somewhereC','/home/someoneC/something/somewhereA']
    return obj


def openUI():
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    dialog = myWidget()
    dialog.show()
    app.exec_()
openUI()
```

Comment: Check the spelling on `mouseReleaseEvent` and `self.setAcceptDrops` in that method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but that won't make a difference. The issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess though it seems appropriate here.

One weird phenomenon that happens perhaps only in older pc's, is that some bits stored seem to have more permanence than others.  These bits seemed to be more difficult to erase or replace with others.  A well known text editor (TextPad) would lock up and refuse to do anything until something cycled out.  It which automatically saved every few minutes.  Eventually it seemed something prevented its ability to recover the end of file location.  The memory problem seemed to go beyond current date and time.   Hope this helps.